# taking element screenshot with pyscreenshot

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, screenshot

I am trying to take screenshot of specific element in web page using Selenium and Pyscreenshot.

Here are my codes:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get("https://kmong.com/?gclid=Cj0KCQiA7briBRD7ARIsABhX8aBKVDTUh1xRgGdYVos02DXaVzR-YWe66W9HTYcG_459B0XKpSnAt4MaArhYEALw_wcB")
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="kmongNavBar"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a/img')

location = e.location;
size = e.size;
print(location)
print(size)

x = location['x']
y = location['y']
z = location['x']+size['width']
h = location['y']+size['height']

im=ImgGrab.grab(bbox=(x, z, y, h))
im.save('test.png')
```

I want to get this:
[image]

Instead I'm getting this:
[image]

So I must assume pyscreenshot takes picture of are on my SCREEN not selenium screen.

How do I address coordinates to limit solely on Selenium page?

> Ok, thanks to comment, I got this working:
>
> driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="catch"]').screenshot("catch.png")
>
> but now this does not save the file, rather open in browser.
>
> How do i change code to save the file instead??

Comment: If my issue involves using pyscreenshot in the first place, pls suggest other modules i can use in Linux-python3. Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use pyscreenshot, you can directly use webdriver for this as shown below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.example.com/')
browser.save_screenshot('image.png')
browser.quit()
```

**EDIT:**
`WebElement`'s have a `.screenshot()` method that you can use for taking screenshot of that particular element.

Comment: yeah but i need screenshot of single element. Any ideas pls?

Comment: Plus, does chromedriver offer screenshot function?

Comment: Yes all drivers offer this functionality. Simply change the driver and url to your need's